# Unwrap Optional when using Collectors maxBy with groupingBy

Tags: java, java-stream

I have a class with a `String` and an `int` field.

```
public class Data {
    private String name;
    private int value;

    private Data(String name, int value) {
        this.name = name;
        this.value = value;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public int getValue() {
        return value;
    }
}
```

I have a `List<Data>` and if I want to create a map (grouping) to know the Data object with *maximum value* for each *name*, I could do like,

```
Map<String, Optional<Data>> result = list.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Data::getName,
                    Collectors.maxBy(Comparator.comparing(Data::getValue))));
```

But, the RHS is wrapped in an Optional because of the contract of `Collectors.maxBy` but I want a `Map<String, Data>`.

One option I could think of it to use `Collectors.collectingAndThen`, but I will have to create an unnecessary intermediate map.

```
list.stream()
         .collect(Collectors.collectingAndThen(Collectors.groupingBy(Data::getName,
                Collectors.maxBy(Comparator.comparing(Data::getValue))),
                map -> map.entrySet().stream()
                        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey,
                                 e -> e.getValue().get()))));
```

Is there an idiomatic way to achieve this using streams?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use `BinaryOperator.maxBy` with `Collectors.toMap`

```
Map<String, Data> result = list.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Data::getName, Function.identity(),
            BinaryOperator.maxBy(Comparator.comparing(Data::getValue))));
```

Comment: Simple enough.. I just missed it.

Comment: @Nikolas I believe it does. Do you see a problem?