# Get Max Value from List in Java

Tags: java, arrays, list, sorting, arraylist

I have a list like below

```
List{        
{Type=A, Amt=30000},{Type=A, Amt=50000},{Type=B, Amt=40000},{Type=B,Amt=60000},{Type=C,spRqstAmt=50000},{Type=C,Amt=10000}
}
```

I need to print the max amount for each Type.

Output:

Type: A,
Amt: 50000

Type: B,
Amt: 60000

Type: C,
Amt: 50000

How to achieve this?

Comment: You can use HashMap to store Type as key and Amt as value

Comment: I think [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63159541/4207306) is perfect for your case

Comment: We are not a homework writing service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the below code . This should work for you . There could be other approaches also , this is using HashMap.

Data Class

```
class Data{
    String type;
    int amt;
    
    Data(String s , int a){
        this.type = s;
        this.amt = a;
    }
}
```

Implementation Class:

```
        Data data1 = new Data("A",30000);
        Data data2 = new Data("A",50000);
        Data data3 = new Data("B",40000);
        Data data4 = new Data("B",60000);
        Data data5 = new Data("C",50000);
        Data data6 = new Data("C",10000);
        
        ArrayList<Data> al = new ArrayList<>();
        al.add(data1);
        al.add(data2);
        al.add(data3);
        al.add(data4);
        al.add(data5);
        al.add(data6);
        
        
        
        HashMap<String,Integer> hm = new HashMap<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < al.size(); i++) {
            if(hm.containsKey(al.get(i).type)) {
                int tempAmt = hm.get(al.get(i).type);
                if(al.get(i).amt > tempAmt) {
                    hm.put(al.get(i).type, al.get(i).amt);
                }
            }else {
                hm.put(al.get(i).type,al.get(i).amt);
            }
        }
        
        System.out.println(hm);
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming a class:

```
class DataClass {
  public String type;
  public Integer amt;
}
```

You can:

```
HashMap<String, Integer> values = new HashMap<>();
for (DataClass data : listDatas) {
  if (values.contains(data.type)) {
     int amt = data.get(type);
     if (data.amt > amt) {
       values.put(data.type, data.amt);
     }
  } else {
    values.put(data.type, data.amt);
  }
}
```

Then you can print the results.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your list contains objects of type Element, aggregate them using `toMap` collector into map where type is a key and value conflicts are resolved in favour of greatest value:

```
Map<String,Integer> m = list.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(Element::getType, Element::getAmt, Math::max))
```

(code from top of my head, I didn't tested it)

Answer (score 0):

Similar to the answer of Tomáš Záluský, using the stream API but this way you retain the `Element` objects, if you need them later:

```
import static java.util.Comparator.comparingInt;
import static java.util.function.BinaryOperator.maxBy;
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.toMap;

Map<String, Element> groupByMax = list.stream()
                .collect(toMap(Element::getType, e -> e, maxBy(comparingInt(Element::getAmt))));
Collection<Element> elementsWithMaxAmts = groupByMax.values();
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no real need to use streams in this case.  Give the following list of maps:

```
List<Map<String, String>> list =
        List.of(Map.of("Type", "A", "Amt", "30000"),
                Map.of("Type", "A", "Amt", "50000"),
                Map.of("Type", "B", "Amt", "40000"),
                Map.of("Type", "B", "Amt", "60000"),
                Map.of("Type", "C", "Amt", "50000"),
                Map.of("Type", "C", "Amt", "10000"));
```

You can use the `merge` method of `map` to combine the results.

```
Map<String, String> results = new HashMap<>();

for (Map<String, String> m : list) {
    results.merge(m.get("Type"), m.get("Amt"),
            (a, b) -> Integer.valueOf(a)
                    .compareTo(Integer.valueOf(b)) == 1 ? a :
                            b);
    
}
results.entrySet().forEach(System.out::println);
```

Prints the following with the type showing the maximum amount.

```
A=50000
B=60000
C=50000
```